# How to put components in one line / block?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I need to situate alerts one one line with buttons. They appear in different situations (states), but even this they doesn't appear more than 1 in the same time. Just need to show them in one line with 'Send button'.   doesn't help.

Thanks for any help.

This is my code:

```
      <Form.Group className="m-0">
        <Form.Control>
// starting here
        <Button>
          {isLoading ? 'Sending...' : 'Send feedback'}
        </Button>
        {isLoading && showTimer && (
          <CancelButton         )}
        {tooShortFeedback && !isLoading && (
          <WarningAlert message="Your feedback must be more than 10 symbols" />
        )}
        {attemptCount && (
          <DangerAlert message={tooLong} />
        )}
        {tooLongFeedback && !attemptCount && (
          <WarningAlert message={tooLong} />
        )}
        {feedbackNotSent && !isLoading && (
          <DangerAlert message="Your feedback was not sent. Try again" />
        )}
// finishing here
      </Form.Group>
```

This is schema how it looks now:

**Button**

**Alert**

And this is what I need:
**Button Alert**

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to achieve

Comment: @CaptainMhmdrz_A my allerts are shown under 'Send message' button. and I need to show it in one line with this button. i tried it with <span>, but it didn't work

Comment: kinda like `display:block` and `display: inline- block` stuff?

Comment: i can't understant, to be honest. see my edited post

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @CaptainMhmdrz_A in the comments. You need to update the CSS of these buttons.
From `display:block` to `display:inline-block` or `display:inline`

Answer (score 0):

To get everything in one line you could use `display:flex`

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```
    <div style={{display:'flex'}}>
        <Button>
          {isLoading ? 'Sending...' : 'Send feedback'}
        </Button>
        {isLoading && showTimer && (
          <CancelButton         )}
        {tooShortFeedback && !isLoading && (
          <WarningAlert message="Your feedback must be more than 10 symbols" />
        )}
        {attemptCount && (
          <DangerAlert message={tooLong} />
        )}
        {tooLongFeedback && !attemptCount && (
          <WarningAlert message={tooLong} />
        )}
        {feedbackNotSent && !isLoading && (
          <DangerAlert message="Your feedback was not sent. Try again" />
        )}
    </div>
```

Comment: this doesn't help